# return array value by index if given else return the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ternary-operator

Is it possible to return an arrays value by its index if the index-number is given and otherwise to return the complete array, without repeating yourself?

We have for example the following function:

```
$.fn.getMatrix = function(i){
    return this.css('transform').split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',')[i];
};
```

...if the `i`-paramter is unset i want to return the complete array.

Any ideas how to accomplish this, in observance of DRY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$.fn.getMatrix = function(i){
   var array = this.css('transform').split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
   return (typeof i === "number") ? array[i] : array;
};
```